# How to find which pip package owns a file?

Tags: python, pip

I have a file that I suspect was installed by `pip`. 
How can I find which package installed that file?

In other words, I'm looking for a command similar to `pacman -Qo filename` or `dpkg -S filename`, but for `pip`. Does it exist? Or should I use some combination of `pip` and `grep`?
In that case, I don't know how to list all the file installed.

Comment: What do you mean with “file”? A module? A package?

Comment: @poke In my hd I have a file  .py and I want to know if I installed a package years ago that copied that file into my computer. (actually the file is `/usr/bin/rst2html.py`) but my question is how to do it in general.

Comment: Related: [Which python package owns a binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55864568/5353461)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 (pip): find which package provides a particular module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63847850/python3-pip-find-which-package-provides-a-particular-module)

Answer (score 15):

You could try with

```
pip list | tail -n +3 | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs pip show -f | grep "filename"
```

Then search through the results looking for that file.

Comment: Thanks, it almost works. But, for most of the packages I get `Files:
Cannot locate installed-files.txt` is it an issue of my system?

Comment: @KraZmAzzD: I think `pip list` includes packages that weren't installed by `pip` itself, but by your system package manager. These will usually not include the `installed-files.txt` file.

Comment: @Rörd grep may work, but it would need context (several lines up) to get the actual package name not just the file name.

Comment: For users of future `pip` versions: `s/pip list/pip list --format=legacy/` if you get an error `no such option: ----------------`.

Comment: Replace `grep "filename"` with `grep -B10 "filename"` to show some more metadata from the package in question (which or may or may not reflect the directory used in the `Files` section.

Answer (score 3):

Since Python 3.8 standard library offers a more straightforward approach than [Nathaniel 's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49521482/1032586):

```py
import pathlib
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
else:
    import importlib_metadata


path_query_pattern = sys.argv[1]
for dist in importlib_metadata.distributions():
    paths = dist.files

    for file in dist.files:
        if pathlib.Path(file).match(path_query_pattern):
            print(dist.metadata["Name"] + ' --- "' + str(file) + '"')
```

The backport of the `importlib_metadata` for [older](https://github.com/python/importlib_metadata/blob/b22b8a79d3996213807a0b0746952201a98b19c1/setup.cfg#L18) python versions is [available via pip](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/).
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49923876) answer.

Usage:

```
>>> python lookup_file.py pip.exe
pip --- "..\..\Scripts\pip.exe"

>>> python lookup_file.py Scripts\pip.exe
pip --- "..\..\Scripts\pip.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a python script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
try:
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import get_installed_distributions

MYPATH=sys.argv[1]
for dist in get_installed_distributions():
    # RECORDs should be part of .dist-info metadatas
    if dist.has_metadata('RECORD'):
        lines = dist.get_metadata_lines('RECORD')
        paths = [l.split(',')[0] for l in lines]
    # Otherwise use pip's log for .egg-info's
    elif dist.has_metadata('installed-files.txt'):
        paths = dist.get_metadata_lines('installed-files.txt')
    else:
        paths = []

    if MYPATH in paths:
        print(dist.project_name)
```

Usage looks like this:

```
$ python lookup_file.py requests/__init__.py 
requests
```

I wrote a more complete version here, with absolute paths:

https://github.com/nbeaver/pip_file_lookup

Comment: It seems that `pip.utils` is renamed to `pip._internal.utils.misc` after pip version 10.0.0b1.

Comment: @nekketsuuu Yes, it's an issue. https://github.com/nbeaver/pip_file_lookup/issues/2

Comment: @nekketsuuu FYI, [patched now](https://github.com/nbeaver/pip_file_lookup/commit/b53a7d2e86d9e829ad5fcc807689a82d732759be).

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
find_pkg_by_filename(){ for pkg in $(pip list | cut -d" " -f1) ; do if pip show -f "$pkg" | grep "$1" ; then echo "=== Above files found in package $pkg ===" ; fi ; done ; }

find_pkg_by_filename somefilename
```

Note that if you add `-q` to the `grep`, it will exit as soon as there's a match, and then pip will complain about broken pipes.