# Are there any function replacement for pip.get_installed_distributions() in pip 10.0.0 version?

Tags: python, pip, installation

When I try to import pip package and use pip.get_installed_distributions(), console is printing error:

```
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_installed_distributions'
```

Are there any solutions which exclude downgrading pip?

Answer (score 23):

#### Update

With Python 3.8, the standard library has got a way of querying the environment for installed distributions and their metadata: [`importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html). For older Python versions, there's a backport [`importlib_metadata`](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/):

```
$ pip install importlib-metadata
```

It is thus advisable to use it (or the backport) instead of relying on `pip`'s internals.

Importing with backwards compatibility:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    from importlib import metadata as importlib_metadata
else:
    import importlib_metadata
```

Usage examples:

Get names, versions and licenses (check out more available metadata keys in [core metadata spec](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/)) of all installed distributions:

```
dists = importlib_metadata.distributions()
for dist in dists:
    name = dist.metadata["Name"]
    version = dist.version
    license = dist.metadata["License"]
    print(f'found distribution {name}=={version}')
```

Querying single distribution by name:

```
wheel = importlib_metadata.distribution('wheel') 
print(wheel.metadata["Name"], 'installed')
```

#### Original answer:

The function was moved to the `pip._internal` subpackage. Import example with backwards compatibility:

```
try:
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import get_installed_distributions
except ImportError:  # pip<10
    from pip import get_installed_distributions
```

Answer (score 9):

@hoefling It is not recommended and is bad practice to import items from pip._internal pip has warned against this and preceding the release of pip 10 they made an [announcement](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-October/031642.html) regarding this too.

A good alternative would be to use setuptools `pkg_resources` instead. From there you can use `pkg_resources.working_set`. See the comment from @pradyunsg [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5243).

```
import pkg_resources

dists = [d for d in pkg_resources.working_set]
# You can filter and use information from the installed distributions.
```

Comment: While I understand your intentions, I highly discourage the ignorant and sudden decision regarding the API move. A lot of package developers (including myself) relied on public API like stuff in `pip.pep425tags` for years. Now all of the sudden, all of it is moved and lots of projects are broken, and all that is left are some arrogant commentaries about _people do actually use bad examples because they are the first thing they find that works_ (from the link you've posted).

Comment: So while your answer is correct, the _real_ bad practice here is what the pip devs did. They should leave the old modules in place with the import of moved modules and issue a `DeprecationWarning` for at least a version - like this being done in lots of good projects out there, Django being a good example. Instead, now we're forced to look for replacement code. Many thanks to the `setuptools` devs that they adopted the `pep425tags` module, but now I have to work around for the support of old versions of `setuptools` where the module is not available yet.

Comment: Another thing - I don't get a notification when you mention my nickname in the answer; I think this works only in comments for user's answer or where the user commented previously.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Mmelcor answer, the items returned in the list comprehension is a `PathMetadata` object, something like:

```
[wrapt 1.10.11 (/Users/<username>/path/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages),
 widgetsnbextension 3.2.1 (/Users/<username>/path/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages),....]
```

You may need to get the string representation before filtering:

```
import pkg_resources
dists = [str(d) for d in pkg_resources.working_set]
print(dists)
```

Result:

```
['wrapt 1.10.11',
 'widgetsnbextension 3.2.1',...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Summing up the two above, this worked for me

```py
import pkg_resources

lst = sorted(["%s %s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pkg_resources.working_set])

for elem in lst: 

    print(elem)
```