# Distribution not found in importlib metadata when installed in editable mode (pip install -e)

Tags: python, pip, metadata, python-importlib

Using the following snippet found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49923876/11249434) in Python 3.8 to get the distributions installed in my Docker environment.

```py
from importlib import metadata
dists = metadata.distributions()
for dist in dists:
    name = dist.metadata["Name"]
    version = dist.version
    license = dist.metadata["License"]
    print(f'found distribution {name}=={version}')
```

If i install my package in editable mode, i.e.

```
RUN pip install -e /src/my-project/python/my-project
```

it doesn't show up in `metadata.distributions()`.

Without the `-e` it does. Any suggestions?

Edit: Also worth noting that the package is still importable, even though it's not in `metadata.distributions()`.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ...
LABEL mantainer="..."

# copy this project and install
COPY . /src/my-project
RUN pip install -e /src/my-project/python/my-project 
# also tried: RUN python -m pip install -e ...
```

Directory Structure:

```
my-project
├── Dockerfile
├── python
   ├── my-project
      ├── setup.py
      ├── my_project
         ├── __init__.py
```

setup.py:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my-project',
    version=__version__,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=[]),
    install_requires=[...]
)
```

Comment: Can not reproduce. Please include enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @wim added some additional info. not sure what else to add that might be helpful

Comment: your code is still not reproducible, please paste actual code instead of redacting information (which is likely causing your issues)