# How do I determine which gem owns a file?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Let's say I have a file in my `GEM_HOME`'s bin directory, like `~/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin/foo` or something along those lines.  How can I determine which gem owns that file?

---

Here are similar questions for other package managers; I'm looking for an answer specifically for Ruby gems:

- [python/pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483818/how-to-find-which-pip-package-owns-a-file)
- [apt](https://superuser.com/questions/179353/how-do-i-find-out-which-package-owns-a-file/964671)
- [yum/rpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133495/how-do-i-find-which-rpm-package-supplies-a-file-im-looking-for)

Answer (score 1):

Open the bin file and look at its contents. It should be just a plain Ruby file. Somewhere towards the end you will usually see something like this:

```
load Gem.bin_path('gemname', 'gemname', version)
```

Where `gemname` will be the name of the gem the file belongs to.

If a line like that is not present, you will have to do a bit of detective work, but usually you can figure it out from either the bin name, or the code that is in the file itself.

You can also quickly verify `bin` contents of a specific gem like this, which may help in tracking down candidates:

```
gem contents gemname | grep bin
```

Or if you just want to scan everything:

```
gem contents --all | grep file_you_want_to_find
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a general answer, not an answer that's specific to files in the bin directory (that's just something I gave as an example).

Comment: See my last edit. You can use `gem contents --all` and just grep it for anything you need.