# Which python package owns a binary?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, miniconda

I'm having problems with `~/.local/share/miniconda3/envs/nndl/bin/tput` - it produces output different to my system version, breaking some ANSI colouring.

I'm trying to track down the package which provides this offensive version.

I've tried ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33484229/5353461)):

```
pip list | tail -n +3 | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs pip show -f | grep tput
```

But the binary is not shown.

How do I find which python package includes a binary?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know a general solution to the problem. But in your special case it should be the ncurses package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tput&mode=exactfilename&suite=disco&arch=any

Comment: Thanks @cel, but I use Arch Linux packages and am looking for the python package with the binary that miniconda is putting earlier in my PATH.

Comment: I am very sure that it will be provided by conda's ncurses package. You can check `conda list |grep ncurses` and see whether it is installed.

Comment: @cel How can I tell if you are right? pip doesn't seem to tell me.

Comment: Do you *have* `ncurses` in the env? If yes then it's Occam's razor.

Comment: @tripleee `pip list | grep -q ncurses` is false (with the broken colours environment activated).

Comment: If you examine the `tput` file, is it a binary, or Python code? In the latter case the `import` should reveal which package it's from.

Comment: @tripleee `file` says: `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped`

Comment: Can you run `strings` on it?

Comment: @tripleee It seems to be a regular RedHat binary: https://pastebin.com/TxtZyGz7

Answer (score 4):

### Conda-based options

#### Option 1: Resolve any environment file

The `conda package` command includes functionality for resolving the package of origin given a file. This is provided by the `-w,--which` command.

**Documentation (abridged)**

```
$ conda package -h
usage: conda package [-h] [-n ENVIRONMENT | -p PATH] [-w PATH [PATH ...]] [-r] [-u] [--pkg-name PKG_NAME] [--pkg-version PKG_VERSION] [--pkg-build PKG_BUILD]

Low-level conda package utility. (EXPERIMENTAL)

Options:

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            Show this help message and exit.
  -w PATH [PATH ...], --which PATH [PATH ...]
                        Given some PATH print which conda package the file came from.
...
```

There's a `tput` in my **base**'s `bin/` so running on that, I get:

```
$ conda package --which tput
tput    conda-forge/osx-arm64::ncurses-6.3-h07bb92c_1
```

That is, `ncurses` looks like the culprit.

#### Option 2: Executables Only

There is a neat [Conda Incubator](https://github.com/conda-incubator) package called [`conda-suggest`](https://github.com/conda-incubator/conda-suggest) that I've found useful. This uses a database of executable files from Conda Forge packages to identify what Conda Forge packages provide them.

This again works out nicely with OP's example:

```bash
## install it to base
$ conda install -n base conda-forge::conda-suggest

$ conda suggest message 'tput'
Command 'tput' not found in the environment, but can be installed with # # any of:

    $ conda install -c conda-forge ncurses
```

So, `ncurses` is the only package on Conda Forge that installs this executable.

Unfortunately, the database is not regularly updated and only covers Conda Forge. On the upside, one doesn't need the package installed, and it accepts regex.

Answer (score 2):

#### To find which package some file belongs to in a mixed conda/pip environment

Replace `filename` with the filename you need.

1. search which package installed by pip contains filename:

   ```bash
   pip list | tail -n +3 | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs pip show -f | grep filename
   ```
2. but if it was installed via conda you have to do this instead:

   If inside an active conda env:

   ```bash
   grep filename "$CONDA_PREFIX/conda-meta/"*
   ```

   If not inside an active conda env:

   ```bash
   grep filename ~/anaconda3/envs/ENVNAME/conda-meta/*
   ```

   - replace `~/anaconda3` with the path where your conda resides
   - replace `ENVNAME` with the conda env name you want

---

- the first recipe is from the OP

Comment: Does the `pip list` option normally take a long time? It took more than a minute for me before I cancelled it and tried the second one, which got results in less than a second.

Comment: it might depend on your fs and the conda env size - on my desktop it takes 0.3secs

Answer (score 0):

One ugly solution is:

1. Rename the file
2. Re-install all installed packages one-by-one
   until the file reappears